# sshpass inside bash script works manually but doesn't with cron

Tags: bash, sshpass

I have a problem trying to launch a sshpass in a bash script to be launched by cron.

I program the cron:

`4 14 14 1 1    /Users/manuel/Downloads/prueba.sh`

prueba.sh has this content:

```
export SSHPASS=mypassword
sshpass -e ssh -oBatchMode=no user@host 'cd www;git pull;exit;'
```

Then I get:

`/Users/manuel/Downloads/prueba.sh: line 3: sshpass: command not found`

But if I launch script manually in the terminal, it works. What's the matter?

I tried with the full path of sshpass `(/usr/local/bin/sshpass)` and with parameter `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. I don't know what's my error.

Thanks.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable is often different between cron and a normal shell. Are you sure you got the full path correct? 99% sure this is your problem, but using the full path would fix it

Comment: I get the full path of sshpass with "which" command. Then I try using this path, /usr/local/bin/sshpass and I get:  "Failed to run command: No such file or directory"